# Git diff - listado de archivos de un tipo modificados desde un commit

Tags: git

Quiero obtener los **ficheros de cierto tipo modificados desde un *commit* determinado**.

Tengo el ***comando para listar todos los ficheros modificados*** sin discriminar el tipo:

```
git diff --name-only 501813f6c963a4c77dc9c664237a08d5f9e702ed HEAD
```

Comment: De cierto tipo =? Podrías añadir una salida esperada a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El comando para filtrar por tipo de fichero usando `git diff` sería, por ejemplo para obtener solo fichero con extensión `.php`:

```
git diff -- '*.php'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554987/3919660

Entonces el comando completo puede ser (solo ficheros .php modificados):

```
git diff --name-only 501813f6c963a4c77dc9c664237a08d5f9e702ed HEAD -- '*.php'
```